# Prove the following sets are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: vector-analysis

> Prove that the following sets are open:

> i) $A=\{ (x_1,x_2) \ | \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 < 1 \ \text{and} \ x_2> 0\}$

> ii) $B=\{ (x_1,x_2) \ |\ x_1\neq 0\}$

My attempt:

i)
[image]
I was thinking that I want to get half the distance between $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(x_1, \sqrt{1-x_1^2})$ and half the distance between $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(\sqrt{1-x_2^2},x_2)$, and then take the minimum of those two numbers to be the radius of my ball.

[image]

After a very long time, I noticed that when $(x_1,x_2)$ is in the yellow area, it will be in the ball $B_r (x_1,x_2)$, where $r=\frac{-x_1 + \sqrt{1-x_2 ^2}}{2} $. And when $(x_1,x_2)$ is in the green area, it will be in the ball $B_r (x_1,x_2)$, where $r= \frac{-x_2 + \sqrt{1-x_1^2}}{2} $. So, when we take $r=\min \{\frac{-x_1 + \sqrt{1-x_2 ^2}}{2}, \frac{-x_2 + \sqrt{1-x_1^2}}{2} \} $, we will have an open ball $B_r (x_1,x_2)$ that is contained in $A$.

What do you think?

ii) Let $(x_1,x_2) \in B$, then we have $(x_1,x_2) \in B_r(x_1,x_2)$, where $r=\frac{|x_1|}{2}$. And I draw it as the following:

[image]

Are my answers correct? Thank you!

Comment: In the first example you have to refine it more, the ball you give for the point $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is not contained in the open set.

Comment: @SaúlRodríguez thank you, you’re right. What about now?

Comment: You probably meant $\frac{1-x_2}{2}$ in the last part? Either way, it´s not enough. Think of the point $(0.7,0.7)$. You have to try a solution that´s a bit different

Comment: You should think in 'polar coordinates' for the first one, instead; write that space as concentric (half) circles, and have the radii of your neighborhoods get smaller the closer you get to the x-axis.  Your part b is correct.

Comment: @SaúlRodríguez I see what you mean. I tried a different way, hope it’s correct this time. :) thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah that seems to work. You could also take the ball of radius $\min(x_1,1-\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2})$.

Also, if you have learnt that the inverse image of a open set by a continuous map is continuous, then the set $\{ (x_1,x_2) \ | \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 < 1 \}$ and the set $\{ (x_1,x_2) \ | x_2> 0\}$ are both open, so their intersection must be open.

Comment: @JohnSamples That’s right! Thank you

Comment: @SaúlRodríguez Finally! Thank you so much, I wouldn’t have gotten it without your help.

Comment: np $\quad\quad$